# Find a non-regular expression tag in a specific tags file

Tags: regular-expression, search, tags

I have a tags plugin that I'm adding features to. In order to test that it is working correctly, I need to examine the tags inside a tags file. I am trying to make sure the correct tags appear in the file and they are not there too many times. My test code is in VimL/Vimscript, so this is a VimL question.

One way to do this is to have the tags file open in a Vim buffer, and then use the search() function to search for that text. Then I just check to see if it appears at the beginning of the line. The problem is search() accepts a regular expression, which is not what I am providing it.

I could bring in each line as a string and examine them one at a time, but that sounds slow and like more work compared to getting search() to work for me.

How can I get search() to work without regular expressions, or in some other way find the tags matching a non-regular expression search in a tags file?

Comment: What do you call a "non-regular expression"?

Comment: @romainl a string?

Comment: `:h \V` "very nomagic"?

Comment: Both `foo` and `[bfx]o\{2}` are regular expressions. You are creating issues where there are none.

Comment: @SatoKatsura That very no magic thing will be super helpful both for this and to fix bugs in my search plugin!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a function, that would search for the string literally. Something like this should work:

```
func! SearchLiterally(pat, flags)
    return search('\V'.escape(a:pat, '\\'), a:flags)
endfunc
```

You can even do that:

```
func! ReplaceSearch()
    let cmd=getcmdtype()
    if cmd =~# '[?/]'
        return SearchLiterally(getcmdline(), cmd)
    else
        return getcmdline()
    endif
endfunc

func! SearchLiterally(pat, search)
    return '\V'.escape(a:pat, '\\'. a:search)
endfunc

cmap <F7> <C-\>eReplaceSearch()<CR>
```

Comment: That SearchLiteral() function is totes digi!. It helps to illustrate how to apply the very nomagic trick referred to by @Sato Katsura. I will be able to use this to address the issue in the tags plugin and to fix bugs in my search plugin! I might mark it as the answer once I get a chance to test it and look into more alternatives.

Comment: After examining the help for very no magic `:h \V`, I am not entirely sure this SearchLiteral function will always work. The help talks about backslash being an exception, which is accounted for here, as well as the terminating character (/ or ?). I don't understand what a terminating character is, but could that mess up this function?

Comment: with the termination character `/` or `?` is meant, which is the character that starts and ends the search. However, this does not matter for the `search()` function and in the second example it is escaped as well.

Comment: Even if that is true, I want to understand it. In what context would a character end a search? Normally doesn't a user press enter to end a search?

Comment: @still_dreaming_1 What do you mean with "even if that is true"? It's all there in the help.

Comment: Oh, yes all we ever need is the help. Why should website even exist when we already have our blessed help.

Comment: You are right. The help is very comprehensive and answers most of the questions that are asked here.